# howto multiply rows and sum using footerdata on jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a column name Price and Value. 
And I'm using the footer 
value of the jqgrid.

Example this are the 2 columns Price and Value

```
Price      
$25.00000
$33.82000
$1.00000
$21.87125
 $9.49000
......


Value 
$5,000.00 
$8,107.87
$1,344.00
$4,769.01
$5,372.00 
...
```

how can I get the sum of the **Price**  and **Value** row 
using the footer data.

also , how do I multiple the value of each `row num1 x row num2` and display in `Num1xNum2`

ie

```
Num1  Num2   RESULT
   4     20      80
```

here is my code. 
note: if i use 'sum' it gives me 'NaN' value

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>


    <!------------------------------------------>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.2/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.4.5/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body { font-size: 75%; }
    </style>
 <script type="text/ecmascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.4.5/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;
        $.jgrid.useJSON = true;
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.4.5/js/jquery.jqGrid.src.js"></script>

    <title>Jqgrid data </title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="margin-left:20px">
    <table id="nplGrid"></table>

</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#nplGrid").jqGrid({
            url: 'json/data-bcp2.json',
            datatype: "json",
            colModel: [
                { label: 'Id', name: 'Id', width: 145 },
                { label: 'Symbol', name: 'Symbol', width: 90 },
                { label: 'Quantity', name: 'Quantity', width: 100, align: "right" },
                /*{ label: 'Value1', 
                    name: 'Value1', 
                    width: 80, 
                    sorttype: 'number', 
                    formatter: 'number',
                    align: 'right'
                }, */
                { label: 'Price', name: 'Price', width: 180, sorttype: 'number' , align: "right",formatter: 'currency', formatoptions: { prefix: " $", suffix: " "}},
                { label: 'Value', name: 'Value', width: 180, sorttype: 'number', align: "right",formatter: 'currency', formatoptions: { prefix: " $", suffix: " "} },
                { label: 'Pledged', name: 'Pledged', width: 80, sorttype: 'integer' } , 
                 { label: 'Num2', name: 'Num2', width: 80, formatter:'currency' },  
                 { label: 'Result', name: 'Result', width: 80,formatter:'currency',
                  formatter:function(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                        var amount = parseInt(rowObject.Num1,10),
                        tax = parseInt(rowObject.Num12,10);
                      return $.fmatter.util.NumberFormat(amount+tax,$.jgrid.formatter.currency);
                    } 
                 }  
            ],

            gridview: true,
            rownumbers: true,
            sortname: "invdate",
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: "desc",
            caption: "Just simple local grid",
            height: "100%",
            footerrow: true,


            loadComplete: function () {
                var $self = $(this),
                    sum = $self.jqGrid("getCol", "Price", false, "sum");

                $self.jqGrid("footerData", "set", {invdate: "Total:", Price: sum});

                    sum1 = $self.jqGrid("getCol", "Value", false, "sum");

                $self.jqGrid("footerData", "set", {invdate: "Total:", Value: sum1});
            }


        });

    });

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

JSON data

```
{
   "rows":[
        {
                "Id":"C14999",
                "Symbol":"AA",
                "Quantity":" 1,000.0000 ",
                "Price":" $25.00000 ",
                "Value":" $5,000.00 ",
                "Pledged":"Y",
                "Num1":"4",
                "Num2":"20",
                "RESULT":""
              },
              {
                "Id":"C14999",
                "Symbol":"IRTX",
                "Quantity":" 25,343.2250 ",
                "Price":" $82000 ",
                "Value":" $857,107.87 ",
                "Pledged":"Y",
                "Num1":"12",
                "Num2":"31",
                "RESULT":""
              },
              {
                "Id":"C14999",
                "Symbol":"MMM",
                "Quantity":" 14,344.0000 ",
                "Price":" $1.00000 ",
                "Value":" $4,344.00 ",
                "Pledged":"Y",
                "Num1":"22",
                "Num2":"20",
                "RESULT":""
              },
              {
                "Id":"C14999",
                "Symbol":"FMCX",
                "Quantity":" 28,565.7660 ",
                "Price":" $21.87125 ",
                "Value":" $4,769.01 ",
                "Pledged":"N",
                "Num1":"232",
                "Num2":"20"  ,
                "RESULT":""
              },
              {
                "Id":"C14999",
                "Symbol":"CEB",
                "Quantity":" 122,800.0000 ",
                "Price":" $9.49000 ",
                "Value":" $5,372.00 ",
                "Pledged":"Y",
               "Num1":"2",
                "Num2":"10",
                "RESULT":""
              },
              {
                "Id":"C23456",
                "Symbol":"VETF",
                "Quantity":" 1,398,400.0000 ",
                "Price":" $2.56000 ",
                "Value":" $9,904.00 ",
                "Pledged":"Y",
                 "Num1":"14",
                "Num2":"20",
                "RESULT":""
              }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the bad format of the JSON data. You returns string formatted in some locale close to en-US (`" $857,107.87 "` should be interpreted as the number `857107.87`). Moreover the data are prepended/appended with additional symbols (`$`, spaces). One can't calculate the sum of such wrong formatted data and the property `sorttype: 'integer` will work wrong too if you would use `loadonce: true` (local sorting of data).

One uses typically the input like `857107.87` or `"857107.87"` instead of `" $857,107.87 "` and formats the data *on the client side using [formatters](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter). For example one can use

```
{ label: 'Price', name: 'Price', width: 180, sorttype: 'number', align: "right",
    formatter: 'currency', formatoptions: { prefix: " $", suffix: " "} }
```

As the result the input data `857107.87` or `"857107.87"` will be displayed in the form `" $857,107.87 "`, but jqGrid could calculate the sum in the column.

The last remark. I don't recommend you to use old 4.4.5 version of jqGrid and download it from the URL `http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.4.5/js/jquery.jqGrid.src.js`. I develop **free jqGrid** fork in the current release 4.13.1 available on [GitHub](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), CDNs (see [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs), for example `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.13.1/js/jquery.jqgrid.min.js` or `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.13.1/js/jquery.jqgrid.min.js`), [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/free-jqgrid), [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/free-jqGrid), [bower](http://bower.io/search/?q=free-jqgrid) and [Maren central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfree-jqgrid). You can choose any from the sources.